# Can Someone please explain how For loop is Working here?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Code:

```
list=[0,1,2,3]
for list[-1] in list:
    print(list)
```

output:

```
 [0, 1, 2, 0]
 [0, 1, 2, 1]
 [0, 1, 2, 2]
 [0, 1, 2, 2]
```

**How is the last element of the list coming**

Comment: list[-1] is the last element of the list. For each member of the list, it changes the last element and finally prints the entire list
You can run the code line by line and debug it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of `for <var> in <list>` is used to take every element in the list, iterate over it, and, for the duration of the iteration, store it in `var`.

So, what your code is doing is, it's going through every element of the list `list`. And it is saving that in the last element of the list.

Here's a step-by-step walkthrough of what is happening:

```py
list = [0, 1, 2, 3]

for list[-1] in list:
# First Iteration:
# list = [0, 1, 2, 3]
# First element in the list is 0.
# Store 0 in list[-1]
# list = [0, 1, 2, 0]
    print list

# Second Iteration:
# list = [0, 1, 2, 0]
# Second element in the list is 1.
# Store 1 in list[-1]
# list = [0, 1, 2, 1]
    print list

# Third Iteration:
# list = [0, 1, 2, 1]
# Third element in the list is 2.
# Store 2 in list[-1]
# list = [0, 1, 2, 2]
    print list

# Fourth Iteration:
# list = [0, 1, 2, 2]
# Fourth element in the list is 2.
# Store 2 in list[-1]
# list = [0, 1, 2, 2]
    print list
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, in your code, the loop is based on substitute one of the number, using the print.
So, if you notice it, you will see that, the number of the loop(in your case -1), it will just substitute the last(3 in case).
If you want to test it, try put:

```
for list[0] in list:
```

and it will print you:

```
 **output:
 [0, 1, 2, 3]
 [1, 1, 2, 3]
 [2, 1, 2, 3]
 [3, 1, 2, 3]**
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops are fancy assignment statements. You can write an equivalent `while` loop with an explicit assignment to model the `for` loop's behavior.

```
list = [0,1,2,3]
itr = iter(list)
while True:
    try:
        list[-1] = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    print(list)
```

Each call to `next` returns a successive value from the list. The first three values never change, but the *last* value is sequentially set to the first, second, third, etc. by the assignment statement. When `next` finally reaches the end of the list,  it returns the *current* value, the one set by the previous iteration, namely `2` (not `3` that was in the original list).